# SQLite where clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, compiler-errors, where-clause

I want to select some rows based on the LOCID. How ever I cant write the where clause it is giving a compile error saying incompatible operand types saying String and int.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONAPPS + " WHERE " 
    + KEY_LOCID == id;
```

here is the create query,

```
String query1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATIONLABLES + "("
            + KEY_LOCID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LOCNAME + " TEXT,"
            +  ")";
```

LOCID type is int what may be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not constructing the string properly. You need to have the equal comparison as part of the string.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONAPPS + " WHERE " 
    + KEY_LOCID + " = " + id;
```

This is just one example of why manually constructing SQL strings is not a great idea. In addition to these types errors, you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injections issues. This is when you input is not properly sanitized and the SQL command ends up executing something you did not intend.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against performing filtering based on a concatenated string.  This opens you up to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). (Here are some [examples of how it works](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).)

A safer solution would be:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONAPPS + " WHERE KEY_LOCID = ?"
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
pstmt.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

(This also opens the door for performance gains through prepared statement reuse.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're not actually doing a comparison in the query, you're using Java to compare KEY_LOCID and ID.

Try:`String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONAPPS + " WHERE KEY_LOCID == " + id;`