# I am trying to edit my database but have it edit a specific column. Through Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to edit my database where I can just edit one part of it aka an item price. However, I am not sure how I can compare the data in my database to an ID i'd have in an int variable. So it can then compare and when it finds the correct row its runs the code (which I think I have)

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Update TblAddCarParts SET PartName = @PartName, PartQuantity = @PartQuantity, PartPrice = @PartPrice";
       
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartName", txtPartName.Text);
            
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartQuantity", txtAddQuantity.Text);
           
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartPrice", txtItemCost.Text);
```

Comment: You need yo have where clause in your query.

Comment: something like [SQLite where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11875679)

Answer (score 1):

Like the commentors already stated:
The where clause is probably what you need.

The Text should then be like this:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Update TblAddCarParts SET PartName = @PartName, PartQuantity = @PartQuantity, PartPrice = @PartPrice WHERE ID=@TheID";

sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartName", txtPartName.Text);
            
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartQuantity", txtAddQuantity.Text);
           
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartPrice", txtItemCost.Text);

sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheID", txtID.Text);
```

You said you have an ID, which you have to insert after the "=" and delete "TheID". But Attention: I do not know how your ID's column name is, so if the ID has another name (like idk PartID) then you have to change the parameter before the "=" symbol too, I just guessed! With this clause you can only edit one row. I hope I could make it more clear for you!

Comment: Can you edit your answer to demonstrate how to carry this through with the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` approach the OP has used to mitigate SQL injections?